# SharePoint 2010 Workflow - Email

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I'm fairly new to using Designer workflows.  I have an email notification which goes to a line manager, and in the body of the email there is a link to the 'current item:' which is a multiple choice field.  I have changed the lookup current item from 'string' to Choices, Comma Delimited - that works fine as it list the items tick from the multiple choice, but what I'd like to do is add a space between the items, `i.e. a,b,c, to a, b, c,`

- I have looked at editing the html but I'm a bit lost.

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

You should install http://spdwfextensions.codeplex.com extensions and then use `Replace` function to replace `,` with `,`

1. Create a workflow variable
2. Store the comma separated choice into that field
3. Do a `Replace` and set it to the same variable
4. Use the variable instead of current item